# EventEmitter has no emit

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this node js script:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
    util = require('util');

var pfioObject = function () {
    this.init = function () {
        console.log("started server");
    };
    this.deinit = function () {
        console.log("stopped server");
    };
    this.read_input = function () {
        return 0;
    };
};
console.log(util.inspect(EventEmitter, false, null)); //<--- this shows no method emit either

var pfio = new pfioObject();

var pfioServer = function () {
    this.prev_state = 0;
    this.start = function () {
        pfio.init();
        this.watchInputs();
    };

    this.stop = function () {
        pfio.deinit();
    };
}

util.inherits(pfioServer, EventEmitter);

// add some event emitting methods to it
pfioServer.prototype.watchInputs = function () {
    var state = pfio.read_input();

    if (state !== this.prev_state) {
        this.emit('pfio.inputs.changed', state, this.prev_state);
        this.prev_state = state;
    }

    setTimeout(this.watchInputs, 10); // going to put this on the event loop next event, more efficient
};

// export the object as a module
module.exports = new pfioServer();
```

For some reason the node error says that there is no such object as emit, i have done `npm install events` to see if that will fix it, it didn't. I'm unsure as to why I'm getting this error.

I think somewhere along my code there is an error but I can't see anything.

To run this code I have another script which does this:

```
var pfioServer = require('./pfioServer'),
util = require('util');

console.log(util.inspect(pfioServer, false, null)); //<--- this line shows the pfioServer with out the prototype function watchInputs

pfioServer.start();
```

***EDIT***

I think I may have missed out on some vital bits of code around the event emitter stuff, am looking into instantiation of the event emitter class

**Slight Change**

So instead of `EventEmitter` being inherited, i instantiated it by doing `var emitter = new EventEmitter()`

Then after that I got errors in the `util.inspect` about the object having to be an object or be null.

No success yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two things that had to be changed for the first code-block to run without errors:

- Explicitly instantiate `events.EventEmitter()`:

`var events = require('events'); var EventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();`

- Change the call to `util.inherits`:

`util.inherits(pfioServer, events.EventEmitter);`

The last thing to make the server run is what [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) wrote: fix [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#With_setTimeout) in `setTimeout()`

```
setTimeout(this.watchInputs.bind(this), 10);
```

Comment: could you elaborate more on the bind in the setTimeout, i was thinking of changing it to the event loop next

Comment: The code run by `setTimeout()` (`watchInputs`) contains `this`. `bind` makes the code reference the correct local `this` instead of the global object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#With_setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this line:

```
setTimeout(this.watchInputs, 10);
```

When the timeout is triggered and `this.watchInputs` is called, it has lost its context.

You need to explicitly set the context object (in other words, what `this` inside the method should point to) for that call by using `bind`:

```
setTimeout(this.watchInputs.bind(this), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> console.log(util.inspect(EventEmitter, false, null));
> // this shows no method emit either
> ```

The `EventEmitter` constructor function does not have such a method. `EventEmitter.prototype` has. To print the (non-enumerable) `.prototype` property, you can use `util.inspect(EventEmitter, {showHidden: true})` as @Emissary mentioned in the comments.

> ```
> // this line shows the pfioServer with out the prototype function watchInputs
> console.log(util.inspect(pfioServer, false, null));
> ```

Yes. `util.inspect` does not show inherited properties, only those apparent on the `pfioServer` instance itself.

> ```
> setTimeout(this.watchInputs, 10);
> // going to put this on the event loop next event, more efficient
> ```

I'd rather say it prevents an infinite loop… However, this also destroys the `this` context in the next invokation, which is no more your `pfioServer` instance. See [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)

In your case however, I don't see the necessity of using a constructor and inheriting from a prototype anyway. You're just exporting a singleton object, which you simply could instantiate with an object literal and reference by its variable name.

Comment: It does if it's used correctly :) `util.inspect(obj, {showHidden: true})` [*docs*](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options)

Comment: @Emissary: Still nope. I couldn't find good docs about it, so I've looked it up [in the source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/657cd2c4e5940d32883a6791be41978a6d07afb8/lib/util.js#L238): `showHidden` does only activate non-enumerable properties, but it's still only the own ones.

Comment: it will happily print the the prototype on the EventEmitter constructor is what I was getting at - as per OP use.